# How to get date in YYYYMMDD format using winapi

Tags: c, winapi

```
time_t t = time(0);   // get time now
struct tm * now = localtime( & t );
char dateNow[100];
sprintf(dateNow, "%d%d%d", now->tm_year + 1900, now->tm_mon + 1, now->tm_mday);
int idateNow = atoi(dateNow);
```

If the date today is 2014February14, idateNow == 2014214(*YYYYMDD*). However the required format is 20140214. What minimum change in the above code can attain this.

Comment: Read about `printf` format modifiers.

Comment: `"%04d%02d%02d"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

printf and friends can use [format modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx) to request things like leading zeros.  In your case, the format string should be `"%04d%02d%02d"`.  The `0`s in there say you want leading zeros and the other digits say how many digits you want (minimum).

Since you tagged this as a WinAPI question, I'll point out that there are also Windows-specific functions for formatting dates, such as [GetDateFormatEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  (Don't be confused by the name: it actually formats a date rather than fetching a date format.)  GetDateFormatEx is a little complicated to use because it can do a lot of things, including applying the user's preferred date format.  If you specifically need the yyyymmdd format, then you'd override the user's default date format by providing a ["picture string"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317787%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) like `"yyyyMMdd"`.

Comment: Thank you Adrian; your patience to explain the slightly cryptic format modifiers is greatly appreciated. Good day!